# Does YCM support completion of built in functions?

Tags: c++, c, linux, vim, youcompleteme

This questions relates to using YCM for the C family of languages:

I think I've got YCM configured so that it doesn't crash immediately (long story) and will do some completions such as items it's seen before (if I write `printf` once, it'll complete it for me the second time around) as well as things like `long`, 'int', etc.

However, when I type some familiar builtin functions like `for`, `while` and `switch`, nothing happens.

Why is this?  The same isn't true for Python, only C family languages that rely on the `ycm_extra_conf.py` file.

Comment: Those are not "functions" and this is not YCM's issue tracker or support forum.

Comment: I meet the same problem and work around by the global namespace ::. The for, while, etc are keywords instead of built in functions.

Answer (score 0):

As you know,YCM need to be compiled before it worked.

I don't know how you compile it,but if you need semantic support for C-family languages,you should go to the YCM directory and compile it like this:

    `./install.py --clang-completer`

The above command is for Ubuntu 64bit/Mac/Fedora 64bit,more details is [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)